# Setting and clearing JavaScript intervals depending on browser state

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an application which automatically refreshes the page with fresh stuff from the server. I was trying out the approach with something basic like printing out the time, to test out my approach. I go to the page, and it starts printing the time every 5 seconds in the console. When I switch to offline mode, the auto-printing should stop, and when I come back to online mode, the auto-printing should resume again. So far, I have this:

```
timing = setInterval(function() {       
    urlToBeCalled = '/autoupdate/';
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(d.toLocaleTimeString());
    /*$.ajax(url: urlToBeCalled);*/
}, 5000);

window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) { console.log("offline"); clearInterval(timing);});

window.addEventListener("online", function(e) { console.log("online"); timing = setInterval(function() {.... blah... blah... blah...}, 5000)
```

(The "blah"s are the same code from the `timing` variable above)

It works, but I don't think this is a very proper way to do things. Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: HTML5 Push API, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think about two ways of doing this.

**Using server**

You can make your browser work as a 'listener' from the server using the 
[Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API), its probably the best way, but sometimes you will not have access to make changes in the server.

**Using client**

Create a run loop.

```
var interval;
var hasBeenOffline = true;
var loop = function() {
   // this will be to function that will run every X seconds
   if(online) {
      // if the server are online
      if (hasBeenOffline) {
          interval = setInterval(function() { /* code */ } )
      }
   } else {
      // server offline
      clearInterval(interval)
   }
};

setInterval(loop, 1000);
```

In this way you will have the a better control of the application flow, and will not be required to create the same interval twice in your code.

Some frameworks use a similiar approach, read about the [Ember Run Loop](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/applications/run-loop/) to know more about the concept.